# Devise update_without_password gives ForbiddenAttributesError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I added additional fields to my user model, then updated the configure_account_update_params method accordingly. Everything was working until I wanted users to be able to update their information without having to input their current password.

So I removed the field for the view and changed the update method in the RegistrationsController

This is my controller, I'm not sure if I'm missing something

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  before_filter :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  def update
    resource.update_without_password(resource_params)
  end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  def configure_account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << [:first_name, :last_name, :country, :phone_number, :gender, :birthdate]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to devise documentation, you should replace this in your controller.

```
    class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

      protected

        def update_resource(resource, params)
         resource.update_without_password(params)
        end
   end
```

Comment: That together with the `configure_account_update_params` did it, thanks